# Display mode keeps changing in Ubuntu 19.04 and other versions

Tags: gnome, shortcut-keys, display, intellij, mode

I'm using an additional screen alongside a laptop in my everyday work. The problem is, ever since I switched from Windows 10 to Linux, whenever I turn on PyCharm (CE) Display Mode is being switched *[just like I have pressed SUPER + P or Fn + F4 - menu pops up letting me choose whether I'd like to use both screens cloned and so on. There is only ~ 1 second to respond before it switches to some random mode. Even if i'll manage to put the cursor on the right place it still changes their places - left with the right one) - EDIT to clarify]*

I've tried Linux Mint 19.2 (Cinnamon), Kubuntu 19.04, Ubuntu 19.04 and 19.10, to check which distribution will suit me best. Finally, I've decided to stick with Ubuntu, yet the problem kept occurring in every single one of those distros. What is more, in both Ubuntu 19.04 and 19.10, the problem also occurs while launching Settings.

I've managed to solve this problem in Kubuntu by simply deleting a shortcut (Fn + F4) that changes Display Mode. I can't do this in Ubuntu since there is no shortcut for Display Mode available to change via Settings / Devices / Keyboard Shortcuts.

Is there any other way to stop the screens switching, or a way around to disable that Shortcut?

Comment: Can you change the display mode with *SUPER+P*? (Super is the same as the Windows Key)

Comment: Yes. How can it help?

Comment: It lets you change the display mode (Duplicate, Extend, etc.) so maybe it will work for you?

Comment: This is not a problem. I do know and use SUPER + P shortcut. Changing Display Mode is what I'm trying to avoid, but it keeps happening every time I launch PyCharm or just Settings while the second display is connected.

Answer (score 0):

I got the exact same issue on my laptop today, and had to use the same workaround as you in Kubuntu (disable all keyboard shortcuts for switching display mode). I found a way to do it in Ubuntu here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/400098

Go in the dconf-editor via the command "dconf-editor" in a terminal, then go at:

```
/org/gnome/mutter/keybindings/switch-monitor
```

and disable "use default value" and delete:

```
'<Super>p', 'XF86Display'
```